# In android, Unable to register multiple events in alarm manager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to register multiple events for different timings. But I am facing a problem, I see notifications for all the events simultaneously.

Please find my code here:

```
            long startTimeinMillies = element.start; // Starting time in ms
            long currentTimeinMillies = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long Difference = startTimeinMillies - currentTimeinMillies;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyReceiver.class);
            myIntent.putExtra(EVENT_DATA_EXTRA, element.title); // Unique value
            int value = (int) element.id; // unique value
            myIntent.putExtra(EVENT_DATA_EXTRA_ID, value);
            myIntent.setAction(System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),value, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Difference,pendingIntent);
```

Kindly let me know, what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that you are executing that block of code several times, and expecting that you will get several alarms, that will not work. Your `PendingIntent` needs to differ by more than the extras on the underlying `Intent`. As it stands, you are replacing existing alarms, not adding new ones.

Replace the `0` in your `getBroadcast()` call with `value`. If your comment is correct, and `value` is unique for each alarm, that should be sufficient to give you separate `PendingIntent` objects for each alarm.

Comment: The same was been done. I have edited back my question. Yes, this piece of code runs multiple time in a for loop and sets different values. All the events are been registered in a calender for different timings(approx a difference of 3-5 mins) but inspite showing different events notification for different timing, it shows all together for all the events

Comment: @Aada: Then use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to examine what is actually getting registered with `AlarmManager`